# Accessing vector in class

Tags: c++, class, vector

If I have a vector as a private member in my class, what's the best way to access it? For example, take the following simple class

```
class MCL{
    private:
    std::vector my_vec;

    public:
    // Include constructor here and other member functions
}
```

What's the best way to access my_vec? Specifically, I would like to use a getter function to access it.

Comment: Access it in what way?  A few specific vector methods? the whole vector?

Comment: @GWW, I want to get the entire vector

Comment: A copy of the container?  A reference to the container?  Do you need the container itself or is access to the sequence of elements sufficient?  There is no one best practice:  it depends on what is stored in the container, how expensive the element type is to copy, and what you need to do with the container and the elements stored in it.

Comment: I would like a reference to the entire vector. I believe that the comment that Andrew gave would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return it by const reference, or just by reference if you want to allow changing.

```
const std::vector<T> & getVector() const
{
    return vector;
}
```

usage:

```
const std::vector<T> &v = myClass.getVector();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public function called

std:vector getMyVec() {return my_vec;}

Comment: this will return a copy

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the semantics of your class, you may want to implement operator[]:

```
T& operator[](int i) {
  return my_vec[i];
}
```

This way you can user [] to access the contents of your vector:

```
MCL a;
a[0] = 3;
std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
```

Note that this may be considered abuse of operator[] or bad practice, but it is up to the developer to judge if this construct fits in the class, depending on its semantics.

Also note that this solution does not provides a way to insert or delete elements from the vector, just access to the elements already there. You may want to add other methods to do these or to implement something like:

```
T& operator[](int i) {
  if(my_vec.size() < i)
    my_vec.resize(i+1);
  return my_vec[i];
}
```

Again, it is up to the semantics of your class and your usage pattern of it. This may or may not be a good idea.